# How can we implement functionality similar to Dash?

Tags: cocoa, text, input, code-snippets

Specifically, how can we observe input to match snippets and how can we cause an input window to appear with modifiable content for insertion in text fields and views on OS X?

Comment: There are two separate questions here. You might get more/better answers by splitting them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of Dash, Bogdan, graciously shared the technique. 
Basically, you need to suffer through the test of will that is using the Accessibility API.